# Obter valores de chave primária em Table Adapter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Como posso obter todos os valores de chave primária em um *Table Adapter*.

Um a um eu consigo obter no momento do insert com este código:

```
PegaIdOrc = orcTableAdapter.GetDataByMaxIDOrc().
            Rows[0]["Expr1"].ToString();
```

Mas quando tento obter todos os valores de uma consulta, me retorna os números pré inserção assim: `-1, -2, -3...`

Já tentei um `foreach` com a contagem de linhas, mas o retorno são sempre estes números negativos.

Comment: Como você esta fazendo o insert? e qual banco de dados esta utilizando?

Comment: Marconcilio, o problema não acontece durante o insert mas sim, quando o datagridview já contém os itens da consulta. Já consegui mudar a query de modo que os id's sejam apresentados em uma coluna com alias e consegui obter todos os id's fazendo um foreach no Datagridview. O que ainda está atrapalhando é a última linha em branco que o DGV gera automaticamente me retornando zero. O BD é Access.

Comment: Deixa ver se entendi, você tem um datagridview  que recuperar os ids dele é isso? é aplicação Windows.Forms coreto?

Comment: Os id's que desejo recuperar são as chaves primárias da consulta de itens do BD que preenchem o DatagridView e que compõem a coluna de índice zero. Sim, é Windows.Forms. Neste momento eu já consegui fazer o código funcionar com o comando que informei no comentário acima e já fiz o procedimento para ignorar a última linha vazia que o DGV gera automaticamente, checando se o campo tem valor null. Vou deixar o tópico aberto um tempo, talvez apareça uma solução melhor.